# Usage of " " inside a concat statement in excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, excel-formula, concatenation

I'm working on data cleansing of a database and I'm currently in the process of changing the upper case names into proper case. Hence, I'm using excel to have an update statement like this:

```
          A  | B   |        C        |       D       |
|  1  | Name | id  | Proper case name| SQL Statement |
|-----|------|-----|-----------------|---------------|
|  2  | AAAA | 1   |Aaaa             |=CONCAT("UPDATE table SET Name = "'",C2,"'" WHERE id = ",B2,";") |
|-----|------|-----|-----------------|---------------|
|  3  | BBBB | 2   |Bbbb             |=CONCAT("UPDATE table SET Name = "'",C3,"'" WHERE id = ",B3,";")|
```

The SQL state should be something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET Name = 'Aaaa' WHERE id = 1
UPDATE table SET Name = 'Bbbb' WHERE id = 2
```

I'm finding it difficult to get apostrophe around the name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need:

```
=CONCATENATE("UPDATE table SET Name = '",C2,"' WHERE id = ",B2,";")
```